# Where is a place located?

Tags: word-choice

What word should I use for telling where a place is located?
I want to use the word in my website. and I want to use it in cases like these:
xxxx: Italy
XXXX: Swiss Alps, Switzerland
XXXX: Alberta, Canada
XXXX: French Polynesia
XXXX: Washington
XXXX: Yosemite Valley, Yosemite National Park, California
XXXX: Central Switzerland
XXXX: South Africa
I think the word should be 'Address' or 'Location'. But I'm not sure. Please help me. thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Location is just right. When you use "address", people expect a much more specific location than a country, state, city, or national park.

Comment: Does it work for country?

Comment: Yes. "Location" is broad enough for all your...locations. If your locations were very different in nature and scope, for example one a house address and another a country, you'd have to break it down, calling one an address, another a country, and so on.

Comment: Location could even refer to the whole planet or galaxy, if that's the level you're interested in. "Location: Earth" vs "Location: Mars".